# How to get element by element from XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I was able to get my first element from  this list

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetITARListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetITARListResult>
        <ClassificationCode>
          <code>dsd</code>
          <description>toto</description>
          <legislation>d/legislation>
        </ClassificationCode>
        <ClassificationCode>
          <code>dsd</code>
          <description>tata</description>
          <legislation>dsd</legislation>
        </ClassificationCode>
        <ClassificationCode>
          <code>code2</code>
          <description>dsds</description>
          <legislation>dsd</legislation>
        </ClassificationCode>
```

by writing

```
XDocument result = new XDocument();
result  =   ExportControl.ResultXML;
var codes = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML_Templates/codes.xml");
dynamic root = new ExpandoObject();
XmlToDynamic.Parse(root, xDoc.Elements().First());
var result = xDoc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/") + "code").First();
```

which get the the first code "dsd". But what if I want a foreach and get all the code? or what if I want a certain code ?  for example

```
var result = xDoc.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/") + "code")[2]
```

Comment: use `XmlReader` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your code fragment makes little sense, xDoc comes from nowhere. And use either XDocument _or_ Dynamic, you don't need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net framework provides a set of tools you can use to move over an XML file:

1. **XmlReader**: this class reads xml files in hierarchical manner and only forward
   without cached.
2. **XmlWriter**: this class writes in xml files only forward without
   cached.
3. **XmlDocument**: it helps you to navigate and edit small documents as it's
   slower than XmlReader/Writer. It uses XmlNode objects to move through your document and perform changes (attributes). After editing your you can save. A nifty way to navigate is by using XPath
   (query language for xml).
4. **XPathNvigator**: class offers an easy way to navigate through an XML document.

In your case, my recommendation is to implement a couple of methods one for iteration and one for location of a particular node with XmlReader and [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) respectively.

Update: the XML example is malformed here:

```
<legislation>d/legislation>
```

This shows you an example to read the file:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace XMLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
                            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                              <soap:Body>
                                <GetITARListResponse xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
                                  <GetITARListResult>
                                    <ClassificationCode>
                                      <code>dsd</code>
                                      <description>toto</description>
                                      <legislation>d</legislation>
                                    </ClassificationCode>
                                    <ClassificationCode>
                                      <code>dsd</code>
                                      <description>tata</description>
                                      <legislation>dsd</legislation>
                                    </ClassificationCode>
                                    <ClassificationCode>
                                      <code>code2</code>
                                      <description>dsds</description>
                                      <legislation>dsd</legislation>
                                    </ClassificationCode>
                                  </GetITARListResult>
                                </GetITARListResponse>
                              </soap:Body>
                            </soap:Envelope>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xml);

            var items = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ClassificationCode");

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((System.Xml.XmlElement)(item)).InnerText.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
// OUTPUT
// dsdtotod
// dsdtatadsd
// code2dsdsdsd
```

Comment: You leave out the XDocument family, which the OP already uses.

Comment: @Robert thank you for this useful information , as for the typo error, that's cause I erased the codes (confidentials codes) and by mistake i Erased < from /legislation>

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is returning the First item merely because you're calling First() method. In order to loop through all codes you can skip the call and you will get an IEnumerable. Then you can loop like this:

```
var codes = result.Descendants(XNamespace.Get("http://tempuri.org/") + "code");

foreach (var codeElement in codes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(codeElement.Value);
}
// prints:
// dsd
// dsd
// code2
```

To access them by index you can use ElementAt like this:

```
var someCode = codes.ElementAt(1);
Console.WriteLine(someCode.Value);  // prints dsd
```

Or you can filter by name like this:

```
var code2 = codes.Where(c => c.Value == "code2").First();
Console.WriteLine(code2.Value); // prints code2
```