# How do I get a specific element in a XML document?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio

I have a XML file that looks like this:

```xml
<Info>
  <ID>1</ID>
 <Result>
   <ID>2</ID>
 </Result>
</Info>
```

I want to count how many Info/Result/ID I have in this file.
I am doing this:

```cs
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("myFile.xml");
xmlNodeList MyList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Info/Result/ID");
int totalCount = MyList.Count;

// other logic...
```

The method `GetElementsByTagName` does not find any "ID"-field.
I want to get the "ID = 2".

How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element by element from XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417867/how-to-get-element-by-element-from-xmldocument)

Comment: You probably need to adjust your XPATH here: `xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Info/Result/ID");`

Comment: Any suggestions on how to write it?

Comment: Can't you just read the file as string and count how many `</Result>` tags are there?

Comment: No. I need to check how many <Result>-tags that actually have an ID-tag and how many Result-tags that does NOT have any ID-tag.

So therefore, I need to check how many "Info/Result/ID" there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, here´s how:

---

public static void MyCountExample(string myXml, out int myID)

```
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myXml ?? ""));

        var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        myID= 0;

        reader.IsStartElement("Info");
        while (!reader.EOF)
        {
            if (reader.ReadToFollowing("Result"))
            {
                if (reader.ReadToDescendant("ID"))
                {
                        myID++;
                    
                    else
                    {
                        return somethingElse();
                    }
                ......
```

Answer (score 0):

To count all the nodes in "Info/Result/ID" path use this..

```
var count = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Info/Result/ID")?.Count ?? 0;
```

To process these nodes

```
var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Info/Result/ID");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
    var idValue = node.InnerText
    // do something
}
```

Comment: The value "2" is not relevant. 
It´s the structure that I am interested in.

Find all ID:s with Parents Info/Result.

Comment: I've added a new code block to the answer, it should do the job

Comment: It does not do the job. Have you tried it by yourself?

Comment: First of all, I use similar code in my project and it works, And Now I've tested it for your sample data and it worked as well.. I think when something does not work with you, better to tell what happened when you try the code, does it throw an exception? does it return false result (and what was the result).. you can't just use my words and say: "did you try it yourself"! of course I did not come up with this code from my imagination! Answering the question is sort of help, appreciate it..